# Because app requires SDK version >=2.15.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0.

Because app requires SDK version >=2.15.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because app requires SDK version >=2.15.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

here is my flutter --version

```
Flutter 2.10.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision db747aa133 (2 days ago) • 2022-02-09 13:57:35 -0600
Engine • revision ab46186b24
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Comment: Just change the sdk version in your pubspec.yaml to the requested version. Your pubspect should have something like this `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` is change to this `sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"`.

Answer (score 35):

Run `flutter upgrade`, after run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 12):

You should not update the dart version of this project, please open pubspec.yaml file and update

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

to

environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"

Answer (score 3):

like @Yasin Ege says, dart need to upgrade in order to use:

```
flutter channel <channel to update master or beta>
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue.
Go to **pubspec.yaml** and change then make it :

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.15.1 <3.0.0'
```

No need to upgrade flutter if you are already in the latest version. Just do this and I hope this will work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should update dart version, can upgrade dart version [this link](https://dart.dev/get-dart)

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and use the following command to determine your Dart version: `dart --version`.
Copy your dart version and go to `pubspec.yaml` file and change your `sdk version >=2.19.6 <3.0.0` to your current dart version. You have to replace version that is on left side `2.19.6`.

error with Dart SDK version in given image:

[image: error with Dart SDK version in given image]

Replace the highlighted version to your current Dart SDK version:

[image: replace the highlighted version to your current Dart SDK version]

Your current Dart SDK version can be found here:

[image: your current Dart SDK version is here]

Your issue can be easily resolved by following these straightforward steps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

here is my problem

`Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.3.

Because al_quran_app requires SDK version >=3.10.6 <4.0.0, version solving failed.`

1. first check your dart version in your terminal by text :
   dart --version
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb2T4.png)
2. go to pubspec.yaml and change your env sdk to your current sdk
   [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Nye.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLQnn.png)

3. run flutter clean, and then run flutter pub get

Comment: Properly Format the code or answer

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this error by changing :
`flutter_lints: ^2.0.0` To `flutter_lints: ^1.0.0` in `pubspace.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter channel <master or beta>
flutter upgrade
```

But if you check `dart --version` is the version that matches the version the project requires and still get the error "version solving failed." like this.

[image]

```
flutter clean
flutter channel <master or beta>
flutter upgrade --force
```

Answer (score 0):

When prompting your command just use `flutter pub add ...` instead of `dart`

Answer (score 0):

Go pubspec.yaml and edit minimun to your dart version

From
environment:
sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

To
environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

it only run 'flutter upgrade'  is ok.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If none of them worked, try this instead

```
flutter pub cache repair

flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

try this steps :-

1. delete `pubspec.lock` file.
2. run `flutter clean` command.
3. run `flutter upgrade` command.
4. run `flutter pub get` .
5. try run your project.